# How do I create a JWT Token for Prime Trust's API?

Tags: rest, jwt

I am working with [Prime Trust's API](https://primetrust.com/apis) and I'm unable to create a JWT token.  I am following the [documentation](https://docs.primetrust.com/?version=latest#13f3e916-91d4-47d4-a1df-5f5b9b3c190b) which states the following:

> Getting Started with the Custody APIs - (Sandbox Specific)
>
> You need totake the current steps to get started via the APIs
>
> 1. Create a new User
> 2. Authenticate with the APIs by getting a JWT.
> 3. Create an Account.
> 4. Test Mode APIs - Approve the owner of the account for CIP and AML.
> 5. Test Mode APIs - Open an Account for Funds

I was able to create a user following the documentation, but I'm stuck on the creation of the JWT Token. According to the documentation I should create the token using the below:

JSON Web Tokens (JWTs)

JSON Web Tokens or JWTs are the preferred method of authentication for all requests besides actually generating a JWT. Since JWTs are not persisted server resources, they are not created using a JSONAPI style request or response.

> Creating a new JWT
>
> A new JWT can be created by passing a user's credentials using HTTP
>   Basic Authorization to the following endpoint. Any special settings on
>   the JWT such as IP whitelisting, expiration time or TOTP MFA must be
>   passed in as form values during creation.
>
> POST /auth/jwts

Here's the example call they give:

```
curl --location --request POST "https://sandbox.primetrust.com/auth/jwts" \
  --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  --form "expires_at=2019-06-06T07:30:40Z" \
  --form "otp=382948" \
  --form "cidr[]=192.168.1.213/32" \
  --form "cidr[]=127.0.0.1/32"
```

I've tried a combination of different calls with the details outlined below, but have the below error on all of my attempts:

```
401 Unauthorized
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "status": 401,
            "title": "Not authenticated."
        }
    ]
}
```

## Bodies

```
POST https://sandbox.primetrust.com/auth/jwts     

POST https://sandbox.primetrust.com/auth/jwts     
{
    "email": "email@email.com",
    "password": "123abc"
}

POST https://sandbox.primetrust.com/auth/jwts     
{
    "data": {
        "email": "email@email.com",
        "password": "123abc"
    }
}

POST https://sandbox.primetrust.com/auth/jwts     
{
    "name": "name",
    "email": "email@email.com",
    "password": "123abc"
}

POST https://sandbox.primetrust.com/auth/jwts     
{
    "id": {guid},
    "name": "name",
    "email": "email@email.com",
    "password": "123abc"
}

POST https://sandbox.primetrust.com/auth/jwts     
{
    "id": {guid},
    "password": "123abc"
}
```

## Headers

```
Content-Type: application/json
expires_at: 2019-12-31T11:59:59Z
alg: HS256
typ: JWT
```

I recognize that my calls don't line up with the example call exactly, but my understanding from the documentation is that all that *should* be required is a name & password to generate the JWT token. What am I missing?

---

## Update 1

Based on reaching out to Prime Trust support the username/email need to be included as parameters rather than in the body of the url.  I tried the below URLs without success

```
https://sandbox.primetrust.com/auth/jwts?email=email@email.com&password=123abc&id={guid}
https://sandbox.primetrust.com/auth/jwts?email=email@email.com&password=123abc
https://sandbox.primetrust.com/auth/jwts?password=123abc&id={guid}
https://sandbox.primetrust.com/auth/jwts?name=name&password=123abc
```

Answer (score 1):

According to docs:

> **Creating a new JWT**
>
> A new JWT can be created by passing a user's credentials using HTTP Basic Authorization to the following endpoint. Any special settings on the JWT such as IP whitelisting, expiration time or TOTP MFA must be passed in as form values during creation.

So basically all you need is create an **Authorization** header set to Basic Auth with your credentials:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://sandbox.primetrust.com/auth/jwts \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic YOUR_BASE64_ENCODED_EMAIL_AND_PASSWORD' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```